# Access Filemaker 13 Pro Database through Ruby/other

Tags: php, ruby, api, filemaker

I need to access and if possible modify data in a Filemaker 13 Pro Database. As I understand the whole app and database are kept in one file.

Is there any way to programmatically access the data ? Ruby is my preferred tool, but other languages will do.

The current app needs to be kept alive as is.

Comment: See: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/13/fmp/en/html/odbc.19.2.html#1027617

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker 16+ allows you to do that via its Data API, if your DB is hosted in FileMaker server version 16+ then you can use that, otherwise if your DB is hosted with a FileMaker server version < 16 you can give [RESTfm](https://restfm.com) a shot, I used it in the past and it was a bit of work to make it work, but at this point you options are a bit limited.

The other option will be to use ODBC or the FileMaker PHP Api.